# Javascript: Function call on adjacent object?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures

You will have to forgive me, as I am sure this is addressed elsewhere, but I have no idea what to call this bit of syntax or the concept that this example illustrates.  How does this get() function know that the parameter I am passing into it refers to an index of the adjacent array?  I am not giving get() any indication of what object I am referring to, unless putting an object in parenthesis directly next to it has this effect.   Is this correct?  Is there a broader concept here that I am unaware of involving proximity and function calls?

```
function get(prop) {
  return function(obj) {
    return obj[prop]
  }
}
get(1)([1,2,3]);

// output = 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might make more sense if you split `get(1)([1,2,3])` out into 2 lines like this:

```
var get1Function = get(1);
get1Function([1,2,3]) 
// output = 2
```

Note: after execution of this line

```
var get1Function = get(1);
```

`get1Function` is now set to `function(obj) { return obj[1]  }`

Comment: SO, just to be clear; 'get(1)([1,2,3])' passes the array into the get function as a parameter.  I am just no sure why this works differently than get(1, [1,2,3]), which returns 'function anonymous(obj)'.  Get() only takes one parameter, and so I understand why passing in two parameters does not work, but it seems to me that if get() took two parameters, then this -> get(1, [1,2,3]) <- would work (yet it returns an anonymous object).                                                      function get(prop, obj) {
  return function(obj) {
    return obj[prop]
  }
} //-> function anonymous(obj)

Comment: Actually the array does not get passed into the get function at all. There are two seperate function calls going on here. get(1)([1,2,3]) passes 1 into the get function, which returns another function, which is called immediately passing in the array [1,2,3]

Answer (score 3):

There's no magic here. You have a function that returns a function. When you call `get(2)`, the returned function has `2` for the value of `prop`. Your code is essentially equivalent to this:

```
var fn = get(2);
// fn = function(obj) {
//        return obj[2]
//      }

fn([1,2,3]);
// => 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You've just encountered one of the most confusing concepts for early JS programmers. It's called a "closure". MDN has a [good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on this topic.

In general though, you can think of `get` returning a new method where the value of `prop` has been "saved" to the same value it was when `get` was first invoked.

The code example you provided would probably be best understood if we renamed some things and broke it down:

```
function createFunctionToReturnValueForProp(prop) {
  return function(obj) {
    return obj[prop]
  }
}

var getPropertyFor1 = createFunctionToReturnValueForProp(1);

var array1 = [1,2,3];
var array2 = [4,5,6];
var obj = { "0": "foo", "1": "bar" };

getPropertyFor1(array1); // 2
getPropertyFor1(array2); // 5
getPropertyFor1(obj); // "bar"
```